# STM32+CubeMX+HAL Library using pwm toggle output failed

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx

I understand its principle is to use PWM comparison function when CRR = CNT is triggered interrupt and flip level. I set the ARR to 65535 to automatically add it up again. The CRR value is adjusted for each incoming interrupt, however the PWM waveform does not seem to be ideal[image]

This is my cubemx setting
[image]

My TIM_IT code

```
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)
{
/\* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 0 \*/

    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(&htim3, TIM_FLAG_CC1) != RESET)
    {
        __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_FLAG(&htim3,TIM_FLAG_CC1);
        TIM3->CCR1+=10000;
        return;
    }
    if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(&htim3, TIM_FLAG_CC2) != RESET)
    {
        __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_FLAG(&htim3,TIM_FLAG_CC2);
        TIM3->CCR2+=5000;
        return;
    }

/\* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 0 */*
HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim3);
/ USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 1 \*/

/\* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 1 \*/
}\
```